# Table not respecting width OpenOffice / MsWord

Tags: php, laravel, ms-word, phpword, openoffice-writer

I am trying to create some tables in my docx document.
Everything works great when I open my document with OpenOffice Writer , unfortunately my tables width and some other properties are not respected in MsWord.

1)i create two table having same size and same cells but they are not aligned

Writer

[ONE](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/50114204/61127328-3eb82b80-a4af-11e9-9cae-51bb8d0357e6.png)

Word

[TWO](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/50114204/61127366-5f808100-a4af-11e9-81ce-f1624097d94d.png)

Code :

```
$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(10000, array( 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderBottomColor' => '000000'))->addText('DISAMINA', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$section->addTextBreak(2);
$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Stato Reale del Rischio', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()),  "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->stato_reale_rischio."</div>", false, false);

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Dichiarazioni rese dall’Assicurato', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()),  "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->dichiarazioni_rese."</div>", false, false);

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Meccanica in cui si è svolto il sinistro', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()),  "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->meccanica."</div>", false, false);

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Caratteristiche mezzi di chiusura', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()),  "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->caratteristiche_mezzi."</div>", false, false);

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Operatività garanzia', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()),  "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->op_garanzia."</div>", false, false);



$section->addTextBreak(2);
$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(10000, array( 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderBottomColor' => '000000'))->addText('DOCUMENTI ESAMINATI', array('bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));

$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow(100);

$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(4000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000')), '', false, false);
$htmlWriter::addHtml( $table->addCell(6000, array()), "<div style='text-align: justify;line-height: 1.5;'>".$appr->relazione->documenti_esaminati."</div>", false, false);
$section->addTextBreak(2);

$section->addPageBreak();
```

2)I create contents which are not same in MsWord and width is not respected

Writer
[Three](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/50114204/61127499-b8501980-a4af-11e9-86d9-3d92f58dacdb.png)

msWord

[Four](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/50114204/61127539-d3bb2480-a4af-11e9-90bb-0d7f713956a4.png)

```
$table = $section->addTable();

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(2000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderRightColor' => '000000'))->addText('Partite Interessate',  array('size' => 10, 'bold'=>true),array('align' => 'right'));
$table->addCell(8000, array())->addText('', $regularFont);

$table->addRow(100);

$table->addCell(2000, array())->addText('',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3'))->addText('Descrizione',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3'))->addText('Forma',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3','gridSpan' => 2))->addText('Capitale Assicurato',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));

foreach($appr->partiteInteressate as $partita){


$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(2000, array())->addText('',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true));

$table->addCell(2666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText($partita->descrizione,  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) ,array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(2666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText($partita->forma,  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true),array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(666, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText("€.", array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) ,array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(2000, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText(number_format($partita->capitale_assicurato ,2, '.', ',') ,  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) , array('align' => 'right'));
}

$section->addTextBreak(2);

$table = $section->addTable();

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(2000, array('borderRightSize' => 1, 'borderBottomSize' => 1))->addText('Sottolimiti di Polizza',  array('size' => 10), array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(8000, array())->addText('', $regularFont);

$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(2000, array())->addText('', $header, array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(800, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3'))->addText('% C.A.',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2400, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3','gridSpan' => 2))->addText('Limite Indennizzo',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2400, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3','gridSpan' => 2))->addText('Franchigia',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));
$table->addCell(2400, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000','bgColor'=>'D3D3D3','gridSpan' => 2))->addText('Indennizzo Massimo',  array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));

foreach($appr->garanzieAttivate as $g){


$table->addRow(100);
$table->addCell(2000, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText($g->descrizione, array('size' => 10), array('align' => 'right'));

$ca = $g->tipologia_limite == 'Percentuale' ?  $g->limite : "" ;

$table->addCell(800, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText($ca , array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'center'));

$table->addCell(466, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText("€.", array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) ,array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(1934, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText(number_format($g->limite_indennizzo ,2, '.', ','), array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$table->addCell(466, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText("€.", array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) ,array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(1934, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText(number_format($g->franchigia ,2, '.', ','), array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
$table->addCell(466, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText("€.", array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true) ,array('align' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(1934, array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '000000'))->addText(number_format($g->max_indennizzo ,2, '.', ','), array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true), array('align' => 'right'));
}


$section->addPageBreak();
```

I have tried many solutions \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::LAYOUT_FIXED, cell width etc, but none works.

Any help is appreciated....

thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the tool to add pictures in the Stack Overflow editor to include images as part of a question. All information pertinent to a SO question should be *in the question*, not an outside link. Others may be interested in the problem at a later time and the information in an outside link may no longer be available. SO is not a help desk, it's a Q&A repository.

Comment: As to your problem: my recommendation would be to create a simple document with your code. Open the document in Word and save to a different name. Correct the table, save and close. Now open the original file in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and use the Compare feature to look at the Word Open XML of both tables. That should give you a clue as to what is missing/different for Word to understand the requirement. That will make it easier to find the information for your code...